# Running Docker on Ubuntu 18.04 getting error [/bin/sh 1] [:missing] when trying sudo docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a container for a simple app that has a form in html and save the data to MongoDB using Docker but is not working.

I have found a similar question here but it did not solve my problem.

This is my Docker file:

```
FROM node:11
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

And my .yml file is this:

```
version: "2"

services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8081:3000
    links:
      - mongo

  mongo: 
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo  
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've got here. Can you provide the complete output of what happens when you run `sudo docker-compose up`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I was able to fix it. Apparently, I was running another docker build which was also pulling the mongo image from docker hub. It is all working now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. Apparently, I was running another docker build which was also pulling the mongo image from docker hub. It is all working now. 
So for a fix: 
-make sure you are not trying to build a docker image using a service that it is already in use/being pulled by another build. Just remove one of them to make it work using: docker rm '3ab' (the first 3 letters of the code assigned to the build) -f (force it to stop if running) and then run again docker-compose up.